# Spring MVC with AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, aspectj

I have a working spring mvc project. I want to log each request through my controllers with using AspectJ. The relevant code:

The Controller: (in package hu.freetime.controller)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BaseControllerImpl {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class ControllerAspectImpl {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerAspectImpl.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(public * hu.freetime.controller.BaseControllerImpl.*(..))")
    public void logController() {
    }


    @Around("logController()")
    public void log(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        logger.info("Calling Controller method: " + method.getName() + "()");
        try {
            pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The WebAppInitializer:

```
public class CashflowWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

The WebConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "hu.freetime.controller", "hu.freetime.aspect" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ControllerAspectImpl getControllerAspect() {
        return new ControllerAspectImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that only one of the two components is working. If I "turn off" the AOP, the MVC works perfect, but when i "turn on", and I want to go to the main page, I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - .../WEB-INF/views/.jsp
The requested resource is not available.
```

The strange thing is that it wants to map the ".jsp" instead of "index.jsp", as I wrote in the Controller's index() method. I debugged at runtime, and it did stop at the controller method.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your around advice does not return the result of pjp.proceed(). That is the return value of the advised method and **must be returned by the advice!** Otherwise you are turning the advised method into a void as well.

```
public **Object** log(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
...
    try {
        **return** pjp.proceed(); <<< !
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

Comment: It does not have to return anything. See LoggingAspect.java in this 
[example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

Comment: If you don't care about the return value - sure. But the return value of your method is used to create the HTTP response. No return value - no HTTP response: You get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will work

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * hu.freetime.*(..))")
```

Comment: the problem is not with my pointcut, but probably with my configurations. It seems the AOP crashes the dispacher servlet